# MVC area under new URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two projects what were developed separated and now i need to merge the second one with the first.

The first one is just a website and the second is English test that will have his on 'inside' URL's. What i need is the test to run in a URL like:

```
mywebsite.com/english-test/begin
mywebsite.com/english-test/questionary
```

The thing is, my website project's routes works on a different way, i have a database that has my URL's and i check it to see if it's a valid URL. This is the route that will call my class:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{*RedirectUrl}"
).RouteHandler = new RouteHandler();
```

This is my `RouteHandler` class (i'm gonna put it on a pastebin because the code is kind of big): http://pastebin.com/nFfciyBe.

And this is my class that researches the DB for the URL: http://pastebin.com/sCEEKL9b

The English test will have his 'authorized' URL's on this same database, it will work just as the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working after using MVC Areas and making a few changes on my RouteHandler class making it check for areas on the DB.